# hover display block CSS

Tags: css

Im trying to change display to "block" from "none"; am I doing right? Why is not working?

```
#sub_1{     
      display: none !important    
}

.cls1:hover #sub_1{
     display : block !important 
}
```

Please go to the bottom of my code in CSS! Thanks

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/web_developer_888/FC7nR/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ul is not within li tag of class cls. You have closed your li and after that placed ul but acording to your css #sub_1 must be within .cls, that's why it is not working so change your html to

```
<li class='cls1'>item 2
    <ul id='sub_1'>
        <li>item A</li>
        <li>item B</li>
        <li>item C</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Hope you understand....... let me know if there is any query

Comment: One more question how can I keep it display:"block" as long as I hover over cls1 which has ul with the id of sub_1 as well

Comment: It says I have to wait 5 minutes to accept it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

I have correct your [**code**](http://jsfiddle.net/riazshah/FC7nR/3/) you should understand the hierarchy of HTML then write code accordantly.

```
#header ul li ul{ display:none;}
```

Comment: It seems you fixed the problem of hover; now in your code even when you hover on ItemA,ItemB,.. still they are display:block; how did you solve it? I dont see you add anything in this regard, but how did you solve it? Can you show it in my updated code:jsfiddle.net/web_developer_888/FC7nR/4